# quickblox + setComplexProperty

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm studying the Quickblox Android [API](http://sdk.quickblox.com/android/com/quickblox/chat/model/QBChatMessage.html) and I don't understand what the third argument (`<any> parser`) for the [`setComplexProperty()`](http://sdk.quickblox.com/android/com/quickblox/chat/model/QBChatMessage.html#setComplexProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object--) method means:

```
public Object setComplexProperty(String name, Object value, <any> parser)
```

Can anybody help me with some example please?

Answer (score 0):

This is used for our WebRTC module internal things and actually you don't need this in client app

Here is the top level documentation of Android Chat

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

but anyway  - this object should implement **MessagePropertyParser** interface